# Where, if ever, is it proper (expected) to use a space? Where by convention is it [preferred, or preferred not] but allowed, or forbidden?

Tags: notation, soft-question, convention

The only place I see a space (aside from within tables) inserted with some regularity is surrounding an equals sign to more clearly separate a right-hand from left-hand side of an equation. Aside from that, I have encountered similar places where it has been both inserted and left out, particularly within some containerized object of at least somewhat distinct constituents ⟨[{(a, b, c, ...)}]⟩, but more commonly without. Besides maintaining consistency within single handling, is there a standard correct usage (and non-usage) of a using a space in mathematical statements?

Logically I would think that a space should be used between more distinct parts, such as solutions within a set as contrasted to coordinates assigned to a solution. One place where absence of a space could hinder clarity is with an especially long number, particularly one with an absval greater than or equal to 10^6 that in normal entry often has comma[,]s (sometimes space[ ]s or period[.]s) for readability. Are there any places where spacing is used without a comma? Ever intentional different lengths of spacing (outside of hand-written text)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about typography, not mathematics. There are typographical conventions that address spacing questions. The $\TeX$ typesetting system implements many of them. If you have a narrow version of your question you might ask it at tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It is about mathematical notation, which is clearly based in mathematics. If you want a more focused question, consider separate cases of within and outside of parentheses and different types of brackets and various usages.

Comment: The only general rule is, as you suggest, do what makes your work easiest to read. How spacing influences that is a combination of taste, convention, and case by case analysis. There are no rules.

Comment: @victamon While you are surely asking about mathematical typesetting, I don't believe there is any mathematical content in it. As Ethan suggests, the TeX manual (and its extensions in LaTeX, including the ams packages) will give plenty of details regarding how mathematics is conventionally typeset. The users of tex.stackexchange are much more likely to be helpful in pointing you to resources.

Comment: @ Ethan Bolker: Thank you (and preferred_anon) for the referral ,and for the answer confirming what I've inferred. I posted the question in hopes there would be some surprising (to me) taboos one way or the other (with justifocations), but glad for practicality in readability to take priority.

Answer (score 1):

The best comment above may have been the one about whatever makes it easier to read. Using Euclid's formula as an example, which of these to you find easier?
$$\text{Euclid's formula is } A=m^2-n^2, B=2mn, C=m^2+n^2\text{ with commas}.$$
$$\text{Euclid's formula is }\quad A=m^2-n^2\quad B=2mn\quad C=m^2+n^2\quad\text{ with "\quad"s}.$$
Another case is the right ceiling function after a radical
$$\lceil\sqrt{X}\rceil\quad \text{vs}\quad \lceil\sqrt{X}\space\rceil\quad \text{the latter with "\space" in front of }"\rceil"$$
There must be a hundred places where "space" decisions need to be made.

For more info, you might go to

https://academia.stackexchange.com/

or

https://tex.stackexchange.com/